# Why should i rollback after failed commit

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, transactions

Why should i `rollback` after failed `commit`? In case, if `commit` failed, a DB won't get changes anyway. So why should i call `rollback` this case?

Comment: The transaction doesn't end just because the commit failed.  You want to eliminate the entire transaction.

Comment: Rollback is more useful for multiple commands to a single table or to multiple tables.  Utilizing Transactions and Rollback allow you to enter a transaction with a series of commands then if any one of the individual commits fail you can roll back all commands in the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take [Oracle transaction management documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/transact.htm#CNCPT016) which applies to other database engines as well:

> A transaction ends when it is committed or rolled back, either
>   explicitly with a COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement or implicitly when a
>   DDL statement is issued.

Without specifying the COMMIT/ROLLBACK you may end up with the following situations:

> - A user disconnects from Oracle Database. The current transaction is committed.
> - A user process terminates abnormally. The current transaction is rolled back.

Database transaction management is based on transaction logging:

1. The state transition from old to new is recorded in a redo log.
2. The state transition from new to old is recorded in an undo log.

Because of transaction isolation requirements the data is changed against the actual table structures and it's the locking mechanism that prevents other transactions from seeing uncommitted changes. The actual data is changed because the current transaction needs to read its own writes during the transaction lifespan.

So the actual data is changed but because we have both redo and undo logs we can easily commit/rollback or even rollback **in-doubt distributed transactions** that were successfully committed against a given data source, while the global transaction has failed because other enlisted data source has rolled back.

Rolling back consists in undoing all data changes recorded by the current uncommitted transaction, so you should ROOBACK if the current transaction has failed.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two reasons I can think of why a COMMIT would fail:

1. The dbms is not available or corrupt.
2. A deferred constraint takes effect.

As far as I know, T-SQL doesn't support deferred constraints. And even if it did, it should execute an implicit ROLLBACK on failure anyhow.

As to the dbms not being available or corrupt: Well, if the COMMIT doesn't work, why should the ROLLBACK?

Conclusion: I see no reason why to execute a ROLLBACK when a COMMIT fails.

Comment: At least one should check what "fails" means in your use case. For example SQLite could return SQLITE_BUSY in response to an commit. If one treat this as an failure to commit, the transaction should be rolled back. Without rolling back the transaction the next BEGIN with the affected db connection will fail, since the previous transaction is still active.